# What effect has div tag in html

Tags: html

Sometimes I think that html tag "div"  is doing more than just structuring code

For example here it causes some shift of my element

```
<div class="col-md-2">
     <select id="mySelect" >
     </select>
</div>
```

On the other hand if I just use it without "div" there is no shifting

```
<select id="mySelect" class="col-md-2"> 
</select>
```

Comment: The `div` tag itself does not cause a shift. It's the class on your element.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If you want to see a description of the div tag and all its properties and uses you can google "html div" and get many full explanations..

Comment: It also appears as if you're using Bootstrap which would affect your end results

Answer (score 2):

`<select>`s are, by default, `display: inline`, so their layout is decidedly different from `<div>`s, which are `display: block`.

Based on `col-md-2`, I imagine you're using Bootstrap. `.col-md-2` is declared approximately as

```
.col-md-2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
  max-width: 16.666667%;
}
```

and most of those values only have an effect on block-layouted elements.

I believe you'll see a difference if you make that select display: block:

```
        <select id="mySelect" style="display: block" class="col-md-2"> 
        </select>
```